# I want element (3,2) from a matrix with size (4,4) to try the values of the first column from another matrix with size (3,3) one by one

Tags: matlab, matrix

For example: If I have matrix A and Matrix B:

A =

```
 7     4     1
 4     5     6
 3     6     9
```

> > B = zeros(4,4)

B =

```
 0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0
```

I want I want element (3,2) from matrix B with size (4,4) to try the values of the first column from matrix A with size (3,3) one by one and at each time produce the new matrix. So, the output will be:

B =

```
 0     0     0     0
 0     0     7     0
 0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0
```

B =

```
 0     0     0     0
 0     0     4     0
 0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0
```

B =

```
 0     0     0     0
 0     0     3     0
 0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0
```

How can I do this ?

Comment: A simple `for` loop  would do that! `for k=1:size(A,1);` `B(2,3) = A(k,1) ,` `end`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way would be to turn the `3D` matrix to `1D` vector. You now can write a function that loops over this vector and builds a different permutation of it each time. From each permutation you can reconstruct a `3D` matrix.

How many possible permutations are there for a vector of size `N` ?

Answer is: `N!`

```
function m = computerDifferentPerm(A)
    vec = A(:).';
    m = perms(vec);
end
```

Now `m` is a `N! x N` Matrix.
Each line is a vector corresponding to one permutation of the original matrix. You now have to reconstruct each one into a `3D` matrix.

Comment: can you support me with the code that can do it ?

Comment: @MahmoudHasabEl-Naby I will not write it from scratch. You can try this and comeback whenever you are stuck and ask how to continue. I will add a short code in a moment to help you start though.

Comment: @MahmoudHasabEl-Naby edited. All you have to do is implement a third function for `1 part in second function`. which will return a permutation of vector. Make sure you are getting a different permutation.

Comment: @MahmoudHasabEl-Naby this is even easier than I though... matlab already has `perms` function to do this for you. Look at edited code.

Comment: I know this .. The question how to make these combinations input to each element on the matrix ?!

Comment: @MahmoudHasabEl-Naby use `cell`.
define a `cell` `myCell = cell(factorial(N))` and then iterate over lines and save each reconstructed matrix in `myCell{i}`